# Understanding of curve in the sense of scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The following definition is from Hartshorne.

> Definition. Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. A curve over $k$ is an integral separated scheme $X$ of finite type over $k$, of dimension one.

Let $X$ be a curve, is any point of $X$ other than the generic point of $X$ a closed point of $X$?

Comment: Hint: What does dimension one mean, topologically?

Comment: X is of dimension one as a topological space.

Comment: Dimension one means that a proper closed irreducible subset of $X$ consists of only one point.

Comment: Therefore, the closure of a point which is not generic is ...?

Comment: Let $x$ be a point other than the generic point of $X$. We can let an affine cover $\{U_i\}$ of $X$ cover $\bar x$, then $\bar x=\cup_i(U_i\cap \bar x)$, $U_i\cap \bar x$ is either $x$ or empty, so $\bar x=x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Schemes are sober topological spaces. In particular, if the closures of $x,y\in X$ agree, then so do $x$ and $y$. Let $X$ be an irreducible, one-dimensional sober topological space (e.g., a curve as in the OP) and let $x\in X$ be any non-generic point. Let $y\in \overline{\{x\}}$ be an arbitrary point in the closure. I claim that $x=y$. In fact, we get a chain of non-empty irreducible closed sub-sets
$\overline{\{y\}}\subseteq \overline{\{x\}}\subseteq X$. Since $X$ is of dimension one, at least one of these inclusions must be an equality. But $\overline{\{x\}}\neq X$, for otherwise $x$ were the generic point of $X$. Therefore, $\overline{\{y\}}=\overline{\{x\}}$ and so $x=y$, by sobriety. Since $y$ was arbitrary, we conclude that $\overline{\{x\}}=\{x\}$, i.e., every non-generic point of $X$ is closed.